# I started typing in finder the wrong letter now I can't navigate to a file. How to start from beginning?

Tags: macos, finder

The finder jumps to file starting which the letter I typed. I typed Z, now I want to see files start with Y. If I type Y it will search for ZY but I want to start from the beginning.

How does the system reset search?

Comment: I only just discovered this is a feature a few days ago. I'm pretty sure it wasn't there a few OS versions ago. Does anyone know when it was added?

Comment: It has been there since time immemorial (i.e. it pre-dates OS X). You can try it out in this online emulator of a Mac running System 7: https://jamesfriend.com.au/pce-js/

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I've been using this feature on Macs in 1993

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As nohillside said, you can just wait a couple seconds for the buffer to reset, but you can also hit escape to clear it.

Answer (score 15):

I usually just wait a second or two, and then type the character(s) I wanted to initially.

Comment: You're a magician

Comment: Simple, but effective always works best ;)

Answer (score 7):

Press the arrow up or arrow down key to change the currently high-lighted file. Then you can start typing from the beginning again!